# PowerApps integration with JD Edwards

Tags: power-automate, powerapp, integration, oracle, custom-connector

We have a requirement to fetch and push data into Oracle JD Edwards from PowerApps. The concern is about premium license here as 3000 contractors would be using this PowerApps to enter timesheet entries. Here the cost would be a major factor in rejection of PowerApps as 3000 contractors user accounts needs to be created and 3000 per user license needs to assigned, therefore making the project very expensive.

Instead is it possible we create only one service account using that all contractors setup the PowerApps on their mobile (offcourse once it is fully developed and deployed)? There would be a login page where contractors can enter username and password which would be authenticated from a SharePoint list data based on this authentication the data can then be push to JD Edwards or can be fetched. Based on the login there would be a unique emp id which would exchange info to and from JD Edwards via PowerApps/Power Automate.

Will the above work-around work as here we would only need one premium license.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a [pay-as-you-go plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/pay-as-you-go-overview) for your Power App. This means you only pay when your app is used and reduces the overhead of licence procurement.